# Library Columns Hidden after Refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, viewfields

I have a SharePoint Library with almost 2000 items (each item is a PDF document with some additional standard Fields for metadata).

When using the web UI to show additional columns, they appear at first and all the information for the fields can be seen. The moment I navigate away and back, or simply refresh the page, the columns all become hidden again.

The only columns that remain are: Name, Modified and Modified By.

I have no idea how or why this is happening. Please help!

Comment: Are you using the New Library experience?

Comment: Yes I believe so, the UI has changed.

Comment: You can switch to classic view.

Comment: Thank you. Reverting this particular Library to the Classic experience worked for now. Hopefully MS fix whatever the issue with the new experience is.